# How to download a large text file using HTTPS on an ESP32?

Tags: esp32, spiffs

Trying to create an ESP32 access to a public Spple calendar, but after connecting to the server and saving to SPIFFS it fails at the same point each time. I end up with a file of around 220 kB, when the total file should be 800 kB.

If it's helpful:
Headers from URL show:
Tranfer-Encoding: Chunked
Connection: keep-alive

Arduino IDE:

```
Sketch uses 891474 bytes (68%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 39640 bytes (12%) of dynamic memory, leaving 288040 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've spent way more hours than I'd like to admit even getting here.

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include "FS.h"
#include "SPIFFS.h"

/* You only need to format SPIFFS the first time you run a
   test or else use the SPIFFS plugin to create a partition
   https://github.com/me-no-dev/arduino-esp32fs-plugin */
#define FORMAT_SPIFFS_IF_FAILED true
 
const char* ssid = "House N";     // your network SSID (name of wifi network)
const char* password = "Sebastian1963George"; // your network password
int LED_inbuilt = 2;

void setup() {
  Serial.end();
  delay(100);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED_inbuilt, OUTPUT);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("WIFI status = ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.getMode());
  WiFi.disconnect(true);

  delay(1000);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("WIFI status = ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.getMode());
  
  digitalWrite(LED_inbuilt, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(LED_inbuilt, LOW);
  delay(500);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
 
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
  
  if (!SPIFFS.begin(FORMAT_SPIFFS_IF_FAILED)) {
    Serial.println("SPIFFS Mount Failed");
    return;
  }
} 
 
const char* root_ca= \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIICiTCCAg+gAwIBAgIQH0evqmIAcFBUTAGem2OZKjAKBggqhkjOPQQDAzCBhTEL\n" \
"MAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4GA1UE\n" \
"BxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UEChMRQ09NT0RPIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxKzApBgNVBAMT\n" \
"IkNPTU9ETyBFQ0MgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkwHhcNMDgwMzA2MDAw\n" \
"MDAwWhcNMzgwMTE4MjM1OTU5WjCBhTELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdy\n" \
"ZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4GA1UEBxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UEChMRQ09N\n" \
"T0RPIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxKzApBgNVBAMTIkNPTU9ETyBFQ0MgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlv\n" \
"biBBdXRob3JpdHkwdjAQBgcqhkjOPQIBBgUrgQQAIgNiAAQDR3svdcmCFYX7deSR\n" \
"FtSrYpn1PlILBs5BAH+X4QokPB0BBO490o0JlwzgdeT6+3eKKvUDYEs2ixYjFq0J\n" \
"cfRK9ChQtP6IHG4/bC8vCVlbpVsLM5niwz2J+Wos77LTBumjQjBAMB0GA1UdDgQW\n" \
"BBR1cacZSBm8nZ3qQUfflMRId5nTeTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/\n" \
"BAUwAwEB/zAKBggqhkjOPQQDAwNoADBlAjEA7wNbeqy3eApyt4jf/7VGFAkK+qDm\n" \
"fQjGGoe9GKhzvSbKYAydzpmfz1wPMOG+FDHqAjAU9JM8SaczepBGR7NjfRObTrdv\n" \
"GDeAU/7dIOA1mjbRxwG55tzd8/8dLDoWV9mSOdY=\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
 
void loop() {
  getCalendar();

  delay(1000);
  readFile(SPIFFS, "/calendar.txt");
}

void getCalendar() {
 File file = SPIFFS.open("/calendar.txt", "a");

 if (!file) {
   Serial.println("- failed to open file for writing");
   return;
 }

 if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) { // Check the current connection status
   HTTPClient http;
   http.begin("https://p64-caldav.icloud.com/published/2/MTExOTIzNTUyNDExMTkyM_t4rBfkJzy02anGOy6aHJIsgECeJGkvldH8kJEjylMtRScq7BUY4vOst7NZU_0bLtKJ0JICjDL0ECuF9L_p8lQ", root_ca); //Specify the URL and certificate
    int httpCode = http.GET(); // Make the request
 
    if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) { // Check for the returning code
      http.writeToStream(&file);
    } 
    
    file.close();
    Serial.println("you have finished downloading");
    http.end(); // Free the resources
  }
 
  delay(1000);
}

void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path) {
  Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\r\n", path);

  File file = fs.open(path);
  if (!file || file.isDirectory()) {
    Serial.println("- failed to open file for reading");
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("- read from file:");

  while (file.available()) {
    Serial.write(file.read());
  }
}

void deleteFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path) {
  Serial.printf("Deleting file: %s\r\n", path);
  if (fs.remove(path)) {
    Serial.println("- file deleted");
  } else {
    Serial.println("- delete failed");
  }
}
```

Comment: this sounds like it's begging to be pre-processed on a different computer/VPS, summarized, then provided to the ESP32 in no-mess form.

Comment: Haha, potentially, but I was hoping to get a standalone device that did everything, and it seems like ESP32 should be able to do it, plus I don't have much experience in either, and learning a whole new area of computer programming to get it working seems overwhelming!

Comment: You are basically running out of memory, use [streamHttpClient](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/examples/StreamHttpClient/StreamHttpClient.ino).

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks to dandavis and hcheung! Got that bit working! The project as a whole has defeated me, but you both were really helpful, thanks!